# Flink SQL Streaming - How to Join tables effectively where change of record is nondeterministic

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql

**Kaka topic** (input: table1,table2, output: table3)

**Flink SQL Streaming job**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW distinct_table1 AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date desc) AS rownum
FROM table1)
WHERE rownum = 1;


CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW distinct_table2 AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date desc) AS rownum
FROM table2)
WHERE rownum = 1;


Insert into table3
Select t1.col1,t1.col2..,t1.coln,t2.col1,t2.col2,t2.coln
From distinct_table t1 inner join distinct_table t2 on t1.id=t2.t1_id
```

Rate of change for same record in table1 and table2 is nondeterministic sometime 10k/day and sometime none for month. Kafka topic is configured with compaction

**Edit:**
Distinct SQL clause creates an operator like **Rank[20] -> Calc[21]**

Join clause creates an operator something like **Join[23] -> Calc[24]**
DAG looks like

```
source_t1 ---> rank[20]_calc[21] ---
                                    |>  join[5]_calc[7] ---> Sink
source_t2 ---> rank[10]_calc[11] ---
```

**Question#1:** In this case at some point, state will grow to the extent that exceeds the local disk. What will happen in that case, task manager will fail ?

**Question#2:** In scenarios like above where rate of change is nondeterministic, any configuration that dictates the rocksdb to maintain latest record(not time based where record is purged if no update happened, we have to keep at-least 1 record to make a join) in level0 and purge the older history so that it does not require large disk space and out of disk space issue?

I am assuming operators like **Rank[20] -> Calc[21]** and **Join[23] -> Calc[24]** does maintain the history in rocksdb for each id/PK of corresponding table that is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 When the RocksDB state exceeds the capacity of the local disks, then yes, Flink will fail. As a workaround, you could reshard the state by increasing the parallelism.

#2 What's available is https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-state-ttl, which is not what you've asked for.

In order to get more control over the state retention policy, you could instead write the job using the DataStream API, but that would be a non-trivial undertaking.

Comment: Thanks David. It feels like there is not much option using flink-sql in this scenario. Example i provided above is for the sake of simplicity with fewer tables. In actual scenario, i have 15-20 tables and that results a dag of about 124 operators. Is there anything that we can do per taskmanager outside the streaming pipeline to purge the data older history and keep the latest record ??

Comment: Hopefully FLIP-373 will land in Flink 1.19: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-33397. That said, it's not really clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. `distinct_table1` is already pruning from state all but the latest record for each id -- what more do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: If i am understanding right,
if record1 changed 10 times in different interval like T1.. T10 then at T11 rank and join operator will have the state in rocksdb as of T10 and does not store the history in rocksdb ?

Comment: The history will not be retained in RocksDB as such, but older values will remain as garbage in RocksDB's SST files until they are compacted.